# Code is unreachable -error

Tags: python

newb here, i am trying to compare the difference between a matrix and its tranposed matrix with a tollerance. First thing is i need to check that it is a square and then if  the differnce is with tollerance.I am getting an error that the last two lines of codes are unreachable. The output should be True True for the above but I only get the first True (ie it is a square matrix.

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array(([[1, 2, 3,],[2, 3, 4],[3, 4, 1]]))

def check_symmetric(a,tol):
    b = a.transpose(1, 0)
    print (a)
    print(b)
    rows = a.shape[1]
    col = a.shape[0]
    z= abs(a-b)
    print(z)
    if rows != col: #check to make sure the list is a square
            return False
    return True;
    result = (abs(a - b) <= tol).all()
    print(result)



print check_symmetric(a,tol=1e-8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Move your return statement to the bottom of the function:

```
return True;
result = (abs(a - b) <= tol).all()
print(result)
```

would become:

```
result = (abs(a - b) <= tol).all()
print(result)
return True;
```

A return statement will stop the execution of a function and return control back to the context it was called from, in this case the line:

```
print check_symmetric(a,tol=1e-8)
```

That means the way your code is right now, the last two lines will never be executed because the context for execution is back outside the function already. That's why you don't see that second print statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's a `return True;` just before the last two lines. The function will return at that point, and will never execute those lines. That's why they're unreachable.

Most probably you want to move that line to the end?

Comment: Thanks, how do i make it report that it is either True or False for square and then continue.

Comment: As I understand, you don't want to "report" that it is square. You want to return if it is is symmetric. You're returning `False` the moment you know it's not square, because then it cannot be symmetric. If you don't return there, you know that it is square and go on. You should just remove the `return True` line, and instead of `print (result)`, `return result`. That will be `True` if the matrix is square AND symmetric, and `False` if it's square and NOT symmetric.

Comment: Or, if you want to print "yeah, it's square" before checking if it's really symmetric... then use `print`. But don't return. If you return, that's the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks - that works - as it gives me the right answer if it is a square and either symmetric or not. However if i put a non square array i get Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vertoma/PycharmProjects/read_evans/Q#3rev.py", line 23, in <module>
    print check_symmetric(a,tol=1e-8)
  File "C:/Users/vertoma/PycharmProjects/read_evans/Q#3rev.py", line 6, in check_symmetric
    b = a.transpose(1, 0)
ValueError: axes don't match array   - So how do i get it to report it is not a square and exit without errors - thanks

Comment: You can do one of two things. 1) Test at the very beginning that you've been supplied with a square matrix. You can do that by making sure that `len(a.shape)` is 2 and not other number; and then that `a.shape[0] == a.shape[1]`. Doing that you KNOW it's square, and can go on with the function; or return `False` on the spot. 2) Assume it's square and go on. At some point you'll get an exception like this one. Learn how to capture exceptions in Python